# Can't use read-write files with matplotlib's savefig()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, temporary-files

I'm trying to save my figure in a tempfile. I want to do it in the most pythonic way possible. For that, I tried to use the tempfile, but I ran into a few problems. The savefig function is supposed to be able to take either a filename as a string, or a file-like object, which I don't see violated at all in the first two things I tried.

This is what I tried initially:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix=".png") as tmpfile:
    fig.savefig(tmpfile, format="png") #NO ERROR
    print b64encode(tmpfile.read()) #NOTHING IN HERE
```

What I then tried:

```
with open("test.png", "rwb") as tmpfile:
    fig.savefig(tmpfile, format="png")
    #"libpngerror", and a traceback to 
    # "backends_agg.py": "RuntimeError: Error building image"
    print b64encode(tmpfile.read())
```

What I then tried:

```
with open("test.png", "wb") as tmpfile:
    fig.savefig(tmpfile, format="png")

with open("test.png"), "rb") as tmpfile:
    print b64encode(tmpfile.read())
```

This works. But now the whole point of using the module tempfile is gone, since I have to handle naming and deleting the tempfile myself, since I have to open it twice. Is there any way I can use tempfile (without weird workarounds/hacks)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file has current position at which read, write is performed. Initially the file position is at the beginning (unless you opened the file with append move (`a`) or you moved file position explicitly).

File position is advanced if you write/read accordingly. If you don't rewind the file, you will get empty string if you read from there. Using [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.seek), you can move the file position.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix=".png") as tmpfile:
    fig.savefig(tmpfile, format="png") # File position is at the end of the file.
    tmpfile.seek(0) # Rewind the file. (0: the beginning of the file)
    print b64encode(tmpfile.read())
```